# How to step forward queryset items through related_name to their foreign key item in another model

Tags: django, django-models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)

class Follow(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    userPointer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
    userTarget = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followed", null=True)
```

A users id passes to views, I want return followers queryset.

I have tried:↓ (Using `related_name`)

```
test = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).follower.all()
```

Now a queryset of `Follow` model is generated. But I need each item be translate to it's appropriated `userTarget` foreign key which is followed user.

```
test = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).follower.all().userTarget
```

This does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter

docs = [set.userTarget for set in User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id).follower.all()]
posts = sorted(
        chain(*docs), # Combine docs querysets
        key=attrgetter('timestamp'), # For sorting
        reverse=True # Sorting in reverse order
    )
```

First creates list of querysets of foreignkey items, then merge them to `post` object as final queryset.

Comment: This solution will work, but it wont scale this can cause N+1 queries, since you are looping through queryset.